# equals() implementation for user defined class

Tags: java, equals

I want to know why `equals()` returns False for a user-defined class and not for the String class. (Note that the `equals()` method is not overridden.)

For example:

```
public class EqualsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Employee e2 = new Employee();

        e1.setId(100);
        e2.setId(100);
        //Prints false in console
        System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));
    }
}
```

I know that the `hashCode()` for `e1` and `e2` are different. As a result, the default implementation of equals method returns False.

```
String s1 = new String();
String s2 = new String();
s1.equals(s2); // returns true;
```

I know why it is printing False for user defined; I want to know exactly how the False will be returned.

corrected-- 
I tend say that in Employee class equals method is not overridden.

Comment: Why do you say equals() method is not overridden in String class.

Comment: correcting my mistake equals() method is overridden in String class.

Answer (score 3):

> ...since default equals() method is same for both String and Employee.

Well, that is not true. The `String` class [overrides `equals()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare the contents of the strings.

```
/**
 * Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
 * true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
 * String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
 * object.
 *
 * @param  anObject
 *         The object to compare this {@code String} against
 *
 * @return  {@code true} if the given object represents a {@code String}
 *          equivalent to this string, {@code false} otherwise
 *
 * @see  #compareTo(String)
 * @see  #equalsIgnoreCase(String)
 */
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you said it right, then wrong in your question right there.

The fact that `equals()` is not overridden is why it returns false. `equals()` of the `object` class is meant to check if two reference variables access the same object in memory. You'll need to override that with a `return (e1.getID == e2.getID);`

The `String` class overrides `equals()` and checks for their contents, returning whether they are the same.

[Source - Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

The equals() method compares two objects for equality and returns true if they are equal. The equals() method provided in the Object class uses the identity operator (==) to determine whether two objects are equal. For primitive data types, this gives the correct result. For objects, however, it does not. **The equals() method provided by Object tests whether the object references are equal—that is, if the objects compared are the exact same object.**

To test whether two objects are equal in the sense of equivalency (containing the same information), you must override the equals() method. Here is an example of a Book class that overrides equals():

```
public class Book {
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Book)
            return ISBN.equals((Book)obj.getISBN()); 
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Consider this code that tests two instances of the Book class for equality:

```
Book firstBook  = new Book("0201914670");
Book secondBook = new Book("0201914670");
if (firstBook.equals(secondBook)) {
    System.out.println("objects are equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("objects are not equal");
}
```

This program displays objects are equal even though firstBook and secondBook reference two distinct objects. They are considered equal because the objects compared contain the same ISBN number.

You should always override the equals() method if the identity operator is not appropriate for your class.

source :  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: thank you Vishal i understood the difference.

Answer (score 0):

> ...since default equals() method is same for both String and Employee.

This is not true, `String` class overrides `equals()` method to check the contents of the string.

If you don't override `equals()` method for your class, then object class `equals()` method will be used which just returns true if both reference refer to the same object. Hence for checking equality, you need to override it for `Employee` class.

Read [overriding equals method for user defined classes](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/26/what-is-the-significance-of-equals-method-in-java/) for good understanding.
and when your are overriding `equals()` also override `hashcode()`. [This article](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/28/significance-of-equals-and-hashcode/)helps understand the significance

Answer (score 0):

I believe String class override `equals()` to compare the contents of String. so your code return "true".

In case of user defined object you need to override equals method on the basis of any unique element of user defined object. It could be either Id/Name or combination of both. then only java will able to compare the user defined object on the basis of value they contained.